# EasyAdmin error :"Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType" ,The options "upload_dir", "upload_filename" do not exist

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, vichuploaderbundle

I apologize, my English is very bad. I need your help.

I develop an application with symfony 5. I use EasyAdmin 3 And VichUploader to load image.
this is my vich_uploader.yaml :

```
    vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        site:
            uri_prefix: '%app.path.site_images%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public%app.path.site_images%'
            namer: 'Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer'
```

this is my entity :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Entity\Traits\CommonFields;
use App\Repository\SiteRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation\UploadableField;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SiteRepository::class)
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Site
{
    use CommonFields;
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $logo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100 , nullable=true)
     */
    private $logoName;

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getLogoName()
    {
        return $this->logoName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $logoName
     * return $this
     */
    public function setLogoName($logoName)
    {
        $this->logoName = $logoName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="site" , fileNameProperty="logoName")
     * @var File
     */
    private $logoFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $promotion;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $livraison;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $remboursement;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $support;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $about;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $telephone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $facebook;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $twitter;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $linkedin;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLogo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }

    public function setLogo(?string $logo): self
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPromotion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->promotion;
    }

    public function setPromotion(?string $promotion): self
    {
        $this->promotion = $promotion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLivraison(): ?string
    {
        return $this->livraison;
    }

    public function setLivraison(?string $livraison): self
    {
        $this->livraison = $livraison;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRemboursement(): ?string
    {
        return $this->remboursement;
    }

    public function setRemboursement(?string $remboursement): self
    {
        $this->remboursement = $remboursement;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSupport(): ?string
    {
        return $this->support;
    }

    public function setSupport(?string $support): self
    {
        $this->support = $support;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAbout(): ?string
    {
        return $this->about;
    }

    public function setAbout(string $about): self
    {
        $this->about = $about;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(string $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTelephone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    public function setTelephone(string $telephone): self
    {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setMail(string $mail): self
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFacebook(): ?string
    {
        return $this->facebook;
    }

    public function setFacebook(?string $facebook): self
    {
        $this->facebook = $facebook;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTwitter(): ?string
    {
        return $this->twitter;
    }

    public function setTwitter(?string $twitter): self
    {
        $this->twitter = $twitter;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLinkedin(): ?string
    {
        return $this->linkedin;
    }

    public function setLinkedin(string $linkedin): self
    {
        $this->linkedin = $linkedin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param File|null $logo
     */
    public function setLogoFile(?File $logoFile = null)
    {
        $this->logoFile = $logoFile;
        $this->logo = base64_encode($logoFile);
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getLogoFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->logoFile;
    }
}
```

this is my Entity Crud :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Site;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\BooleanField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateTimeField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\EmailField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ImageField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TelephoneField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextEditorField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\UrlField;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class SiteCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Site::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {

        $name = TextField::new('name');
        $logo = ImageField::new('logoFile','Logo')
            ->setBasePath("/images/site")
            ->setUploadDir("public/images/site")
            ->setFormType(VichImageType::class)
            ;

        $promotion = TextEditorField::new('promotion');
        $livraison = TextEditorField::new('livraison');
        $remboursement = TextEditorField::new('remboursement');
        $support = TextEditorField::new('support');
        $about = TextEditorField::new('about');
        $address = TextEditorField::new('address');
        $telephone = TelephoneField::new('telephone');
        $mail = EmailField::new('mail');
        $facebook = UrlField::new('facebook');
        $twitter = UrlField::new('twitter');
        $linkedin = UrlField::new('linkedin');
        $created = DateTimeField::new('createdAt');
        $update = DateTimeField::new('updatedAt');
        $active = BooleanField::new('isActived');
        $delete = BooleanField::new('isDeleted');
        $by = TextField::new('createdBy');
        if (Crud::PAGE_INDEX === $pageName) {
            return [$name, $promotion, $livraison, $remboursement, $support, $about, $address, $telephone, $mail, $facebook, $twitter, $linkedin, $created, $update, $active, $by];
        } elseif(Crud::PAGE_DETAIL === $pageName) {
            return [$name, $promotion, $livraison, $remboursement, $support, $about, $address, $telephone, $mail, $facebook, $twitter, $linkedin, $created, $update, $active, $by];
        }elseif(Crud::PAGE_EDIT === $pageName) {
            return [$name, $promotion, $livraison, $remboursement, $support, $about, $address, $telephone, $mail, $facebook, $twitter, $linkedin, $created, $update, $active, $by];
        } elseif(Crud::PAGE_NEW === $pageName) {
            return [$name,$logo, $promotion, $livraison, $remboursement, $support, $about, $address, $telephone, $mail, $facebook, $twitter, $linkedin, $active];
        } else {
            return [$name, $promotion, $livraison, $remboursement, $support, $about, $address, $telephone, $mail, $facebook, $twitter, $linkedin, $created, $update, $active, $by];
        }
//        return [
//           TextField::new('name'),
//           TextEditorField::new('description'),
//           BooleanField::new('isActived'),
//        ];
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setEntityLabelInSingular('Paramètre')
            ->setEntityLabelInPlural('Paramètres')
            ->setPageTitle('index', '%entity_label_plural%')
            ->setPageTitle('new', 'Ajouter les paramètres du site')
            ->setPageTitle('detail', 'Paramètre du site')
            ->setPageTitle('edit', 'Modifier les paramètres du site')
            ->setHelp('edit', 'Vous modifez les paramètres du site');
    }
}
```

I got an error with my configureFields function

```
    $logo = ImageField::new('logoFile','Logo')
            ->setBasePath("/images/site")
            ->setUploadDir("public/images/site")
            ->setFormType(VichImageType::class)
            ;
```

i gaot this error :

[VichUploaderBundle Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNulG.png)

```
An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType": The options "upload_dir", "upload_filename" do not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_delete", "allow_extra_fields", "allow_file_upload", "asset_helper", "attr", "attr_translation_parameters", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "block_prefix", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "delete_label", "disabled", "download_label", "download_link", "download_uri", "ea_crud_form", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "getter", "help", "help_attr", "help_html", "help_translation_parameters", "image_uri", "imagine_pattern", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "is_empty_callback", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "label_html", "label_translation_parameters", "legacy_error_messages", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "row_attr", "setter", "storage_resolve_method", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".
```